# Return the button onclick value as GTM variable

Tags: javascript, variables, google-tag-manager

[resource block code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHkBe.png)

Our site uses a repeatable block to highlight "related" or "recommended" resources and we're trying to track clicks of those elements via a GTM CTA Click event. Since the image link is using a button onclick vs a link, I'm trying to return the onclick value.

Here's the code I came up with, but it always returns the value of the first button in the list (not the one actually clicked). How do I adapt this to return the onclick value of the button actually clicked?

```
function() {
var regex = /location\.href=['"]([^'"]+)['"]/;
var code = document.querySelector("div > div.cards-wrapper > div > button").getAttribute("onclick");
var match = regex.exec(code);
var url = match ? match[1] : null;

return url
}
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching eventlisteners to the buttons?

Comment: event listeners attached to buttons is a wrong solution here. Kayla, never show code in screenshots, copy and paste your html snippet here. Also, be more precise. What value do you want to get on CTA click? The url? That's it?